# How to allow any user to log as a non loggable user?

Tags: users, login, authentication, pam

I'm trying to implement the following functionality on Redhat:
I have a user "John" that can't be used to login directly via GDM or console or SSH.
I want to allow any user that are logged onto the system, to be able to log as "John" .
How would you do that using PAM modules or any other manner ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the login shell of user John to `/sbin/nologin` and then login with `su -s /bin/bash John`.

Comment: might be even better if people could use `sudo` which would allow to not share John password

Comment: John's password could also be removed with `passwd -d John` because this should (as far as I remember) prevent any remote access to the account.